# How do I access section of the json using db.adminCommand("top")

Tags: mongodb

When I run `db.adminCommand("top")` the output is

```
{
    "totals" : {
        "note" : "all times in microseconds",
        "admin" : {
            .......
        },
        "app.fc_set" : {
            "total" : {
                "time" : NumberLong("47266389985250"),
                "count" : 5998426181
            }
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I need to access app.fc_set directly

When I try `db.adminCommand("top").totals.app.fc_set.total` I get error I am assuming because **app.fc_set** has a dot inbetween.

How do I access the that section correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `["app.fc_set"]` like `db.adminCommand("top").totals["app.fc_set"].total`.

Also I think the `db.adminCommand("top")` return promise so you can use `(await db.adminCommand("top")).totals["app.fc_set"].total`.